# Continuity of the integral as a function of the domain

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable. Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be measurable. Is $$
r \mapsto \int_{rC} f \, \mathrm{d} \mu,
$$
where $rC = \left\{ rc \: \middle| \: c \in C \right\}$ continuous? If not, is it under some more restricted contiditons on $f$ or $C$ i.e. compactness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally not. If we take $C=\{(x,y )\in\mathbb{R}^2  :y>0\}$ and $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1 \mbox{ if } |x|\leqslant 1 \wedge |y|\leqslant 1 \\ 0 \mbox{ otherwise }\end{cases}.$$ Then the function $$r\to\int_{rC} f(x,y)dxdy$$ is not continuous at the point $0$ because $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ and $\frac{1}{n}C=C.$

You should assume that $C$ is bounded.